# Filtering SharePoint search results based on Location and Country in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We have 10 page libraries in 10 sites/subsites (sites: country and subsite: cities) which are based on "ContentType1".If the site increases the page libraries will also increase. There is a webpart page on which we have a search results webpart. This webpart pulls results from the Content Type1.
Below is the query : `ContentType:"ContentType1"`

Now we want to only pull results to which the user is associated to, we have two columns `city` and `country`. So if the site is country site the user who adds a page will add the country column say "United states" or if the site is city site then the user who creates a page will select the city as "Atlanta, GA"

So below is the query i am having to filter

```
ContentType:"ContentType1" RefinableStringLocation: {User.SPS-Location.Name} OR  RefinableStringCountry: {User.Country.Name}
```

So user belonging to Atlanta, GA, should yield results from the country site which is the united states as well as from the city site which is atlanta, GA.The below query only computes one condition in my case `ContentType:"ContentType1" RefinableStringLocation: {User.SPS-Location.Name}`

If we use one query at one time instead of OR, it yield correct results. But when used OR we only get the Location results not the country ones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about if we are using AND operation instead of OR operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The issue was with the setting called `"do not show duplicates"` Once that was unchecked the results showed up, it is really strange why the other results were treated as duplicates.